# error bootstrap responsive css is disabled in chrome

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

> ERROR: Bootstrap's responsive CSS is Disabled!
>   see http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#respond-file-proto

I can't understand  why I am seeing this error ?
when I try to open my html file this message showing in chrome and after hitting ok then it display the page. but every time I refresh the page this message popup, above mention URL has nothing regarding this issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the official Bootstrap v3 HTML example templates contain the following 3 lines:

```
<!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy these 2 lines! -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../../assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->
<script src="../../assets/js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>
```

Those 2 scripts are present to avoid spurious IE8-related Bootstrap bug reports. As the comment says, **they shouldn't be included when copying from the templates**.

The error message you're referring to comes from the `ie8-responsive-file-warning.js` script specifically.
The `<!--[if lt IE 9]>` IE conditional HTML comment means that this script should only be executed on IE<=8.

Since you're seeing it in Chrome, you presumably:

- Did not heed the warning not to actually copy those lines; and
- Removed the `<!--[if lt IE 9]>` condition for some arbitrary reason.

The solution is to remove the two `<script>`s from your webpage.